# Data truncated for column on mysql UDF

Tags: mysql, c, user-defined-functions

I am writing my first User Defined Function in C to be called from mysql. Code is very simple:

```
char *getKey(UDF_INIT *initid __attribute__((unused)),
    UDF_ARGS *args, char *result, unsigned long *length,
    char *is_null, char *error __attribute__((unused)))
{
    const char *word=args->args[0];
    strcpy(result,"EOOOOOOOO");

    return result;
}
```

I have compiled and loaded it with no problems.

```
CREATE FUNCTION getKey RETURNS STRING SONAME 'udf_key.so';
```

To test it i was calling it within an Insert query:

```
INSERT INTO `seed4c`.`users` (`iduser`,`userscol`) VALUES (1,getkey('aa'));
```

userscol is a Varchar(45), so there should be enough space for the returning string. I am geting a warning

```
1 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1265 Data truncated for column 'userscol' at row 1
```

When making a Select in the table the field has the expected value (EOOOOOOOO) and some strange chars, non alfanumeric.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not setting `*length` to the length of the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add:

```
*length = strlen(result);
```

See the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/udf-return-values.html)